# さてと・・・それじゃあ捜査を始めるとしようか。

Tags: grammar

Here's the sentence :

> さてと・・・それじゃあ捜査を始めるとしようか。

I would have understood if the sentence was : "さてと・・・それじゃあ捜査を始めよう", but I don't understand the rest of the sentence. Is "としよう" some kind of grammar ?

As for the context, the characters were just about to investigate a murder.

Answer (score 0):

捜査を始めよう means "Let's start the investigation", but 捜査を始めるとしようか means something more along the lines of "should we try and start the investigation", basically.
It's along the lines of ～ようとする・～ようにする

食べようとする
I'm about to eat. (I'm going to try to eat) (Maybe you don't have a lot of time or something.)(attempt to do something)

食べるようにする
I will try to eat. (Try to eat something you don't like, or maybe you're sick)(non-momentum, or continuous conscious effort)